# Problem Publishing RShiny App Warning: Computation failed in `stat_summary_hex()`:

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am having a problem publishing my RShiny App. Whenever I publish it, everything works besides my stat_summary_hex() function within my ggplot. I am not really sure why it is not working, whenever I run it through RStudio it works perfectly fine, but not when I publish it. If I could get help, that would be much appreciated.

I am getting this message: Computation failed in `stat_summary_hex()`:

Here's my code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

allStuff2 = read.csv("appData.csv")
allStuff2$player_name = iconv(allStuff2$player_name,from="UTF-8",to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
allStuff2 = allStuff2 %>%
  mutate(pitch_type = ifelse(pitch_type == "FF", "Fourseam Fastball", pitch_type),
         pitch_type = ifelse(pitch_type == "SI", "Sinker", pitch_type),
         pitch_type = ifelse(pitch_type == "FC", "Cutter", pitch_type),
         pitch_type = ifelse(pitch_type == "SL", "Slider", pitch_type),
         pitch_type = ifelse(pitch_type == "CU", "Curveball", pitch_type),
         pitch_type = ifelse(pitch_type == "CH", "Changeup", pitch_type)) %>%
  arrange(player_name) 

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("2022 Stuff+ Dashboard"),
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("journal"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('name',
                  'Select Pitcher:',
                  choices = unique(allStuff2$player_name)),
      selectInput('pitch_type',
                  'Select Pitch Type:',
                  choices = c('Fourseam Fastball', 'Sinker', 'Cutter', 'Slider', 'Curveball', 'Changeup'),
                  selected = 'Fourseam Fastball')),
    
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("stuffPlot"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  pitcherAvg = reactive({
    allStuff2 %>%
      filter(player_name == input$name,
             pitch_type == input$pitch_type) %>%
      group_by(pitch_type) %>%
      summarise(velo = mean(release_speed, na.rm = T),
                pfx_x = -mean(pfx_x, na.rm = T),
                pfx_z = mean(pfx_z, na.rm = T),
                rp_x = mean(release_pos_x, na.rm = T),
                rp_z = mean(release_pos_z, na.rm = T),
                p_throws = p_throws[1],
                Stuff. = mean(Stuff., na.rm = T))
  })
  
 output$stuffPlot = renderPlot({
   ggplot(filter(allStuff2, pitch_type == input$pitch_type, 
                 p_throws == pitcherAvg()$p_throws, 
                 release_pos_x >= pitcherAvg()$rp_x - 0.5, 
                 release_pos_x <= pitcherAvg()$rp_x + 0.5, 
                 release_pos_z >= pitcherAvg()$rp_z - 0.5, 
                 release_pos_z <= pitcherAvg()$rp_z + 0.5, 
                 release_speed >= pitcherAvg()$velo - 1, 
                 release_speed <= pitcherAvg()$velo + 1), 
          aes(x = -pfx_x, y = pfx_z, z = Stuff.)) +
          stat_summary_hex() +
          scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = 100, low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
          geom_point(aes(x=pitcherAvg()$pfx_x, y=pitcherAvg()$pfx_z), colour="black", size = 5) +
          theme_bw() +
          labs(x = 'Horizontal Movement', y = 'Vertical Movement', fill = 'Stuff+', 
            title = paste(strsplit(input$name, ", ")[[1]][1], "'s Stuff+ by Location for ", input$pitch_type, sep = ""), 
            subtitle = "Based off of Pitchers with Similar Release Point and Velocity (Pitcher's Point of View)", 
            caption = 'Email: fran1412@umn.edu') +
          coord_fixed() +
          geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
          xlim(-2.5,2.5) +
          ylim(-2.5,2.5)
  })

  
  output$table = renderTable({
    allStuff2 %>%
      filter(player_name == input$name,
             pitch_type == input$pitch_type) %>%
      group_by(pitch_type) %>%
      summarise(Velocity = mean(release_speed, na.rm = T),
                `Horiz. Break` = -mean(pfx_x, na.rm = T),
                `Vert. Break` = mean(pfx_z, na.rm = T),
                `Horiz. Release Point` = -mean(release_pos_x, na.rm = T),
                `Vert. Release Point` = mean(release_pos_z, na.rm = T),
                `Stuff+` = as.integer(round(mean(Stuff., na.rm = T), 0))) %>%
      select(-pitch_type)
  })
  
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is my dput file:

```
structure(list(release_speed = c(85.9, 97.6, 100.5, 98.9, 87.3, 
100.7, 100.6, 87.3, 95, 100.7, 101.2, 87.4, 102, 87.2, 103.2, 
95.8, 94.3, 93.1, 89, 101, 87.2, 95.8, 101.5, 96.1, 96.2, 85.5, 
88.7, 88.4, 87.7, 90.5, 88.2, 87.2, 101.2, 100.6, 96.1, 95, 85, 
85.7, 102.3, 96.2, 89.3, 88.3, 91.4, 86.1, 96.5, 101.5, 96.4, 
100.7, 84.5, 89.9, 101.1, 94.3, 98.8, 95.7, 95.4, 89.3, 94.7, 
98.1, 94.7, 97, 95.7, 98.5, 98.9, 87.6, 90.4, 86.5, 88.4, 88.3, 
101.9, 98.9, 100.7, 89, 95.4, 99.6, 102.4, 87.5, 87.2, 88, 87, 
95.9, 99.1, 96.5, 91, 85.9, 87.2, 84.8, 87.1, 88, 98.3, 102.1, 
86.3, 99.2, 101.9, 100, 84.7, 86.1, 98.2, 102.4, 99.8, 98.8), 
    pfx_x = c(0.5, -1.12, -0.79, -0.95, 0.52, -0.89, -1.44, 0.26, 
    -1.12, -1, -0.86, 0.2, -0.84, 0.32, -1.2, -1.09, -1.37, -0.54, 
    0.25, -1.12, 0.15, -0.77, -0.84, -0.99, -1.38, 0.26, 0.05, 
    0.32, 0.2, 0.36, 0.29, 0.01, -1.08, -1, -0.75, -0.67, 0, 
    0.27, -0.9, -1.48, 0.33, 0.11, 0.33, 0.22, -0.75, -1.23, 
    -1.25, -1.02, 0.27, -0.13, -1.1, -0.51, -0.91, -0.7, -0.84, 
    0.23, -1.64, -0.96, -0.76, -1.03, -1.53, -1.24, -1.41, 0.48, 
    0.39, 0.09, 0.56, 0.18, -1.08, -0.97, -1.21, 0.5, -1.21, 
    -0.89, -1.12, 0.13, 0.16, 0.39, 0.46, -1.1, -0.79, -1.19, 
    -0.65, 0.28, 0.23, 0.35, 0.1, 0.34, -0.35, -0.91, 0.02, -0.86, 
    -1.02, -0.75, 0.38, 0.08, -1.38, -1.08, -1.02, -1.15), pfx_z = c(-0.63, 
    0.06, 1.22, 0.13, -0.45, 1.3, 1.15, -1.16, 0.64, 1.18, 1.08, 
    -0.75, 1, -0.59, 1.04, 0.29, 0.25, 0.53, -0.62, 0.97, -0.61, 
    0.13, 1.16, 0.32, 0.05, -0.48, -0.4, -0.39, -0.9, -0.42, 
    -0.64, -0.59, 1.24, 1.01, 0.1, 0.25, -1.05, -0.51, 1.12, 
    0.35, -0.63, -0.52, -0.56, -0.69, 0.22, 0.8, 0.48, 1.18, 
    -0.43, -0.34, 1.17, -0.21, 1.07, 0.21, 0.32, -0.49, 0.16, 
    1.35, 0.12, 0.43, 0.57, 1.04, 0.42, -0.56, -0.58, -0.82, 
    -0.37, -0.48, 0.8, 1, 1.33, -0.7, 0.45, 0.95, 1.37, -0.32, 
    -0.57, -0.72, -0.85, 0.3, 1.32, 0.33, 0.51, -0.55, -0.68, 
    -0.58, -0.57, -0.49, 0.17, 1.3, -0.5, 1.21, 1.14, 1.28, -0.72, 
    -0.42, 0.33, 1.37, 1.24, 0.3), release_pos_x = c(-2.18, -1.97, 
    -2.11, -1.72, -1.4, -1.66, -2.19, -1.93, -2.09, -1.89, -1.85, 
    -1.95, -1.89, -2.16, -1.73, -2.2, -2.22, -2.45, -2.07, -2.11, 
    -2.18, -2.24, -1.85, -2.29, -2.23, -2.16, -2.06, -2.07, -1.77, 
    -1.81, -2, -1.85, -1.75, -2.13, -2.14, -2.49, -2.14, -2.05, 
    -1.89, -1.79, -1.71, -1.73, -1.82, -2.08, -2.32, -1.76, -2.03, 
    -1.93, -2.04, -2.13, -1.97, -2.27, -2.2, -2.1, -2.27, -1.94, 
    -1.95, -1.86, -2.27, -2.28, -1.84, -2.21, -2, -1.72, -1.94, 
    -1.73, -1.74, -2, -1.82, -1.89, -1.59, -1.83, -2.12, -2.12, 
    -1.84, -1.92, -2.13, -1.69, -1.9, -2.12, -2.15, -1.98, -2.63, 
    -2.24, -2.02, -1.83, -2.32, -1.96, -1.88, -2.02, -2.29, -2.2, 
    -2.15, -2.43, -1.68, -1.92, -2.05, -1.65, -2.12, -1.91), 
    release_pos_z = c(6.03, 6.29, 6.13, 6.04, 6.32, 6.24, 6.07, 
    6.18, 6.21, 6.07, 6.02, 6.14, 6.17, 6.16, 6.06, 5.95, 6.06, 
    5.8, 6, 6.02, 6.09, 6.14, 6.08, 5.93, 6.08, 6.26, 6.08, 6.12, 
    6.14, 6.04, 6.41, 6.23, 6.08, 6.11, 5.88, 5.95, 6.28, 6.05, 
    6.06, 6.29, 6.27, 6.2, 5.99, 6.23, 6.08, 6.07, 6.09, 6.18, 
    6.1, 6.19, 5.97, 5.95, 6.11, 5.99, 6.25, 5.97, 6.02, 6.15, 
    6.01, 6.04, 6.18, 6.06, 6.03, 6.2, 5.85, 6.25, 6.07, 6.25, 
    6.06, 5.99, 6.28, 6.18, 5.87, 6.15, 6.01, 6.12, 6.2, 6.09, 
    6.09, 5.94, 5.99, 6, 5.74, 6.36, 6.04, 6.16, 5.94, 6.2, 6, 
    5.96, 6.31, 5.99, 5.96, 6.13, 6.17, 6.21, 6.14, 6.04, 6.05, 
    6.21), player_name = c("Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", "Duran, Jhoan", 
    "Duran, Jhoan"), p_throws = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R"), pitch_type = c("CU", 
    "CH", "FF", "CH", "CU", "FF", "FF", "CU", "CH", "FF", "FF", 
    "CU", "FF", "CU", "FF", "CH", "CH", "SL", "CU", "FF", "CU", 
    "CH", "FF", "CH", "CH", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", 
    "CU", "FF", "FF", "CH", "CH", "CU", "CU", "FF", "CH", "CU", 
    "CU", "CU", "CU", "CH", "FF", "CH", "FF", "CU", "CU", "FF", 
    "CH", "FF", "CH", "CH", "CU", "CH", "FF", "CH", "CH", "CH", 
    "FF", "CH", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
    "CU", "CH", "FF", "FF", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CH", "FF", 
    "CH", "SL", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CH", "FF", "CU", 
    "FF", "FF", "FF", "CU", "CU", "CH", "FF", "FF", "CH"), Stuff. = c(110.783365414633, 
    83.9695389876577, 126.982883382714, 100.773492772016, 122.695393953566, 
    119.617766459935, 118.785623163818, 130.831514405023, 61.756262527081, 
    96.8279502585635, 99.8866109055696, 129.196132513915, 100.484491385581, 
    126.11256167432, 119.411360427872, 99.3219706412825, 114.233606464787, 
    85.7119791685036, 130.467610095058, 112.469680863445, 141.219595669374, 
    107.42847854836, 108.245236352338, 99.7562461898892, 125.500229256936, 
    122.603272894611, 140.858949561694, 127.283168181566, 124.003695368084, 
    127.799900621368, 111.05222857869, 123.422997655113, 123.389105069617, 
    110.298869169031, 111.024067639178, 94.9843404478164, 150.783474706561, 
    126.3180435826, 100.726570873835, 119.565181758901, 122.935086985841, 
    141.957127666565, 131.623575183857, 111.648889433675, 79.7759749825627, 
    86.5740112525524, 93.0267990053248, 111.314387796175, 121.148229426222, 
    146.59561919429, 113.787652486095, 110.791517820695, 84.8826511258123, 
    99.281267964766, 95.6569834353375, 139.898066773251, 116.718918712834, 
    98.5337807227119, 96.0645681960684, 63.3208562591806, 108.735190496635, 
    80.3261641922412, 188.974704795231, 117.766297421377, 129.541840071494, 
    134.2787846362, 130.058767183761, 123.568417985415, 84.8628879203198, 
    68.4933286167661, 116.547997910403, 123.002208002103, 94.3192200671762, 
    85.8888577862371, 141.693480608564, 125.100305847327, 121.625166716099, 
    109.272368981841, 107.346832906711, 100.57797732587, 108.425613182612, 
    78.6537787345208, 85.6841619149002, 121.150698692734, 131.428503129421, 
    113.792479159864, 135.83714795316, 112.501339659899, 88.7429637176584, 
    155.705150252501, 137.647519897197, 97.8102480290771, 135.083550736976, 
    140.716728877702, 98.6674738226451, 134.137954477671, 169.959982914227, 
    141.693480608564, 137.731456338842, 93.4183672266801)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```